# emisjolander flipping is not smooth

Tags: android, flipview

I tried using emilsjolander library for flipping a set of images in an album. Every thing works fine.But flipping is  not smooth.Is there any function in the library to make it smooth. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you tried https://github.com/davideas/FlipView

Comment: No..Actually I want the images to be flipped as in an album.